# in_array() in Go

Tags: array, go

This function's objective is very simple.  It takes `array` and checks if `val` is a value inside of this array. It returns whether `val` exists and which is the index inside the array that contains `val`.

Could this be coded in a better way?  How would I implement this to work with any kind of array (the code below works only with arrays of strings)?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func in_array(val string, array []string) (exists bool, index int) {
    exists = false
    index = -1;

    for i, v := range array {
        if val == v {
            index = i
            exists = true
            return
        }   
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    names := []string{ "Mary", "Anna", "Beth", "Johnny", "Beth" }

    fmt.Println( in_array("Jack", names) )
}
```

Go probably provides a similar function, but this is for study purposes only.

Comment: Some stylistic advice not related to the question: don't use snake_case, use camelCase. And switch the return parameters around, `ok bool` and `err error` are usually the second parameter. See e.g. `val, exists := mymap[key]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than tie yourself to only one type (string), you could use the `reflect` package as well as interfaces to make it somewhat type indifferent. The following is my reworking of your code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func in_array(val interface{}, array interface{}) (exists bool, index int) {
    exists = false
    index = -1

    switch reflect.TypeOf(array).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(array)

        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            if reflect.DeepEqual(val, s.Index(i).Interface()) == true {
                index = i
                exists = true
                return
            }
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Note that we now import the `reflect` package. We also changed the types of `val` and `array` to `interface{}` so that we may pass any type in. We then use the `reflect.Typeof()` to glean the reflection `reflect.Type` of the value in the `array interface{}`. We then glean the type with `Kind()`, and use a case to fall into our inner code if its a slice (can add more cases to extend this).

In our inner code, we get the value of the `array` argument, and store it in `s`. We then iterate over the length of `s`, and compare `val` to `s` at the index `i` declared as an `interface` with `Interface()` and check for truthiness. If its true, we exit with a true and the index.

Running the main function with both a slice of strings and a slice of integers, as follows, works:

```
func main() {
    names := []string{"Mary", "Anna", "Beth", "Johnny", "Beth"}
    fmt.Println(in_array("Anna", names))
    fmt.Println(in_array("Jon", names))

    ints := []int{1, 4, 3, 2, 6}
    fmt.Println(in_array(3, ints))
    fmt.Println(in_array(95, ints))
}
```

The above example gets us:

```
true 1
false -1
true 2
false -1
```

### EDIT: June 2021 - refactored the above code as follows:

```
func inArray(val interface{}, array interface{}) (index int) {
    values := reflect.ValueOf(array)

    if reflect.TypeOf(array).Kind() == reflect.Slice || values.Len() > 0 {
        for i := 0; i < values.Len(); i++ {
            if reflect.DeepEqual(val, values.Index(i).Interface()) {
                return i
            }
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

with the runner function:

```
func main() {
    name := "Mary Anna"
    fmt.Println(inArray("Anna", name))

    var empty []string
    fmt.Println(inArray("Anna", empty))

    names := []string{"Mary", "Anna", "Beth", "Johnny", "Beth"}
    fmt.Println(inArray("Anna", names))
    fmt.Println(inArray("Jon", names))

    ints := []int{1, 4, 3, 2, 6}
    fmt.Println(inArray(3, ints))
    fmt.Println(inArray(95, ints))
}
```

Comment: Few things to point out. 1. boolean's zero value is false, so you don't need to set exits. 2. you don't need the `== true` part in the check. 3. using reflect for that simple task is an extremely slow overkill way of doing it.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are good calls. Point three however ignores OP's question "How would I implement this to work with any kind of array?" - you need reflection for that.

Comment: Great answer. I know it's OP's request, but I do think a single return (just returning the index) is enough

Comment: Very good point @evilReiko - I've refactored to only return index, as well as to no longer rely on the Switch statement

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Using reflection for that simple task is a slow and an inefficient way of doing it, your first approach was fine, you could trim it a little, for example:</strike>

```
func in_array(val string, array []string) (ok bool, i int) {
    for i = range array {
        if ok = array[i] == val; ok {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Generic version using interfaces:

```
func in_array(v interface{}, in interface{}) (ok bool, i int) {
    val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(in))
    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        for ; i < val.Len(); i++ {
            if ok = v == val.Index(i).Interface(); ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Z7A4NuqF4J)

Comment: Advising not to use reflection ignores OP's question "How would I implement this to work with any kind of array?" - you need reflection for that.

Comment: @jsanc623 I completely missed that.

Comment: Your use of 'v' and 'in' is rather disconcerting as the next programmer to come along to your code cannot instantly discern what those values are. Code should be self documenting, and as such, variables should be descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Now with go 1.18 and [generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) you can have a type-safe version of this:

```
// Index returns the index of the first occurrence of v in s, or -1 if not present.
func Index[E comparable](s []E, v E) int {
    for i, vs := range s {
        if v == vs {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Couple of notes here:

- You can simplify the interface by returning -1 instead of (ok, val) tuple. This will also make sure the code that uses the function is error-prone and does not use the value w/o checking.
- In your case you may actually want to consider using a set (`map[string]struct{}`) to get a O(1) runtime.
- nit: naming-wise you do not want to have underscores in the function.

Please note that [golang.org/x/exp/slices](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Index) has this exact function among with lots of useful generic code.